# Distinguish between Wi-Fi Captive portal and MitM attack

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, chrome, captive-portal

Not sure whether this should be asked in Super User or here.

How does Chrome distinguish between a Wi-Fi access point intercepting  with a captive portal and a man-in-the-middle attack on HTTPS?

Are they using a preloaded list of **redirect targets** when checking against sites with HSTS or what?

### Man-in-the-middle attack

[image]

### Wi-Fi hotspot message (in recent versions of Chrome)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**About Chrome**

According to https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/privacy/whitepaper.html

> In the event that Chrome detects SSL connection timeouts, certificate
>   errors, or other network issues that might be caused by a captive
>   portal (a hotel's WiFi network, for instance), Chrome will make a
>   cookieless request to http://www.gstatic.com/generate_204 and check
>   the response code. If that request is redirected, Chrome will open the
>   redirect target in a new tab on the assumption that it's a login page.
>   Requests to the captive portal detection page are not logged.
>
> You can disable navigation error tips by unchecking the box in the
>   "Privacy" section of Google Chrome's options.

**About Chromium OS**

https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/network-portal-detection explains :

> Shill, the connection manager for Chromium OS, attempts to detect services that are within a captive portal whenever a service
>   transitions to the ready state.  This determination of being in a
>   captive portal or being online is done by attempting to retrieve the
>   webpage http://clients3.google.com/generate_204.  This well known URL
>   is known to return an empty page with an HTTP status 204.  If for any
>   reason the web page is not returned, or an HTTP response other than
>   204 is received, then shill marks the service as being in the portal
>   state.
>
> Many, or perhaps most, captive portals found in Hotels, Coffee Shops,
>   Airports, etc, either run their own DNS server which returns IP
>   address for all queries which point to their webserver, or they
>   intercept all HTTP web traffic and return a 302 (redirect) response. 
>   The captive portal detection works very reliably with these types of
>   portal to indicate that the service is not fully online.